# Java EE-Timer / @Schedule in Websphere Liberty Profile

Tags: timer, scheduler, schedule, websphere-liberty

I want to use the timer-Service (especially [@Schedule Annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html)) in WebSphere Liberty Profile. Is that possible?

Is there a feature for? https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/downloads/wlp/8.5.5.0/ is nothing ;–(

Answer (score 5):

Update: as pointed out this answer is no longer correct since support was added in June 2015. 8.5.5.6 and newer sports ejb timers.

<s>There is no support for EJB Timers in the Liberty profile. The infocenter details the [supported features](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp) and EJB Timers isn't listed.</s>

If you are interested in the Liberty profile supporting this you could submit a [Request for Enhancement on ibm.com](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=submitRfe&BRAND_ID=181&PROD_FAM_ID=262&PROD_ID=544&COMP_ID=17&OS_ID=16&PRI_ID=3&PRESELECT_DROPDOWNS=true).

Comment: Alasdair, maybe update or remove that answer, since it is no longer valid :-)

Comment: I've added an update. If I'm honest because I don't want to lose the points from the answer which was correct for years.

Answer (score 1):

EJB timers are fully supported with WAS Liberty as of 8.5.5.6 (which is fully compliant with Java EE 7).

Answer (score 0):

You should have support for Timers in last Beta (May 2014). They will work but with some issues (I can't invoke EJB methods from timer methods for examples) and there is no persistent timers support yet.