# Creating an EJB Timer in Liberty

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, ejb, websphere-liberty

I need to create a EJB timer (using @Schedule), but have read that this is not supported in a Websphere Liberty profile?  According to a previously posted question on StackOverflow, it wasn't supported as of 08/2013:

[Java EE-Timer / @Schedule in Websphere Liberty Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074656/java-ee-timer-schedule-in-websphere-liberty-profile)

Currently when I try to use the @Schedule annotation I get the following exception:

```
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0004E: An exception occurred while starting the application 
<EAR>. The exception message was: com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ejbPersistentTimer feature is enabled, but the defaultEJBPersistentTimerExecutor persistent executor cannot be resolved. The most likely cause is that the DefaultDataSource datasource has not been configured. Persistent EJB timers require a datasource configuration for persistence.
```

The problem is I DO have a default data source defined.  Here is the EJB code - it is very simple because I was just trying to test out timer functionality:

```
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class TimerBean {

    @Schedule(second="*/10", persistent=false)
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }

}
```

**Update:**

I changed my dataSource id to "DefaultDataSource", and now I am getting a different exceptions in my console when starting the server:

```
[ERROR   ] WTRN0078E: An attempt by the transaction manager to call start on a transactional resource has resulted in an error. The error code was XAER_RMERR. The exception stack trace follows: javax.transaction.xa.XAException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Could not find stored procedure 'master..xp_sqljdbc_xa_start'.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXAResource.DTC_XA_Interface(SQLServerXAResource.java:647)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXAResource.start(SQLServerXAResource.java:679)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbXaResourceImpl.start(WSRdbXaResourceImpl.java:1189)
at [internal classes]

[ERROR   ] J2CA0030E: Method enlist caught javax.transaction.SystemException: XAResource start association error:XAER_RMERR
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredResources.startRes(RegisteredResources.java:1048)
at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.transaction.xa.XAException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Could not find stored procedure 'master..xp_sqljdbc_xa_start'.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXAResource.DTC_XA_Interface(SQLServerXAResource.java:647)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXAResource.start(SQLServerXAResource.java:679)
```

Is this the result of the timer attempting to write to my SQL DB, and if so, is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Is the app starting even though you have these error messages?  Or does this fail the application start process?

Comment: It was not starting because of the messages.. I since replaced ejb-3.2 with ejbLite-3.2 and put my database name back to what it was and everything is working correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have the `ejbPersistentTimer-3.2` feature turned on, since you are getting exceptions for having a DataSource configured.

If you are going to use `ejbPersistentTimer-3.2` (or `ejb-3.2` which includes it) you need to configure a datasource to be used for persistent timers.

Since you don't need persistent EJB timers (because you have `persistent=false` in your `@Schedule` annotation) you can remove the `ejbPersistentTimer-3.2` feature and just use the `ejbLite-3.2` feature (which doesn't include the persistent timer feature).

The `ejbLite-3.2` feature includes support for non-persistent timers, and you won't need to worry about configuring a DataSource.

Comment: I am currently using the ejb-3.2 feature, which includes ejbPersistentTimer-3.2 (according the console output).  So even when removing ejbPersistentTimer-3.2 I still get the same result.

Comment: @schuno I was referring to `ejbLite-3.2` not the full `ejb-3.2`.  The Lite feature does not include persistent timers.

Comment: thank you! Once I changed from ejb-3.2 to ejbLite-3.2 it worked!

Comment: @aguibert can create a small example how to use non persistence timers.

Comment: @Mindaugas an example of using non-persistent timers is shown in the OP.  The key is having `@Schedule(.... persistent=false)`

Answer (score 1):

EJB timers are supported with WAS Liberty provided you use 8.5.5.6 or newer which is fully compliant with Java EE 7.

Comment: Hi Alasdair, I'm using version 8.5.57, so according to what you said this should be working.  I changed my dataSource id to "DefaultDataSource", and now I am getting a new excpetion (I added the new exception as an "Update" to my original question).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a new *Database Store* and provide it a reference to a Data Source.  If you don't have one for the EJB timer tables or want a distinct one you can create a *Data Source* underneath the *Database Store*.  Ensure you provide it an `ID`
2. Add *EJB Container* -> *EJB Timer Service* -> *EJB Persistent Timers Scheduled Executor*
3. On the *EJB Persistent Timers Scheduled Executor* set the **Persistent task store reference** to the `ID` of the *Database Store*

That should get rid of the error and will not require you to switch to EJB Lite.

Answer (score -1):

From the IBM article at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1404_vines1/1404_vines1.html, it looks like it is not available and you'll have to go third party:

> The EJB Timer Service is not supported on Liberty profile or Liberty Core.
>   If your application uses the EJB Timer Service, you can select one of these options:
>   Deploy this part of your application in the WebSphere Application Server Full profile.
>   Use other third-party scheduling libraries.
>   Note: Although the second option is listed as a complex approach, its complexity can be simplified if a small number of timers are involved.

**Update:**

A little further research found this thread which seems to offer a solution (at least there's an accepted answer):

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/187132/ejbpersistenttimer-32/

Comment: Outdated, no longer valid.